# Was there a synagogue inside the Temple?

Tags: synagogue, beis-hamikdash

I vaguely remember seeing in Mishnayos (probably second half of Moed, maybe Taanis - potentially in connection to where the Maamados said their Tefillos - but can't find it now) that there was a Shul within the Beis haMikdosh. I can't seem to find it on any of the floorplans though now. Can someone please confirm and provide a source?

Comment: See the end of [Tamid 4:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Tamid.4.3?lang=bi) - the Kohanim would read *keriat shema* and recite certain *berachot* in the *lishkat hagazit*.

Comment: Also Yoma 7:1 and Sotah 7:7-8

Comment: @JoelK - ok shkoiach. So accompanying the Tomid every day, there was the Shema and some Brochos said in the Lishkas haGazis. Very interesting. In Tomid 5:1 the brochos include "Avoda" - do you know what that refers to? (Also I had understood the Lishkas haGazis as mainly the Court for the Sanhedrin - but presumably they could only sit between the times of these tefilos)

Comment: @Heshy - shkoiach! I think it was the Sota one where I saw it. Where it refers to the "Rosh haKenesses" - does this mean a place called a beis knesses inside the beis hamikdosh (i.e. the lishkas hagazis)?

Comment: @Etzbah Rambam understands Avodah to be Retzei

Comment: @JoelK - a groisse shkoiach. Its so interesting that there were tefillos in the BhM! Especially when we say tefillos replace the korbanos...

Comment: Wasn't the whole beis hamikdash be considered a holy place for prayer? For sure higher in status than a regular synagogue.

Comment: כי ביתי בית תפלה יקרא

Comment: I recall a reference in _mishna_ somewhere (perhaps _Tamid_ or _Yoma_) to "חזן" or "סגן" which the commentaries there say refers to a synagogue worker. Of course, that there was a synagogue worker doesn't mean there was a synagogue in the usual sense.

Comment: Rashi (Yoma 68b, ד"ה בית הכנסת) says exactly that: there was a Beis Knesses on the Har Habayis, near the Azarah (and it's the חזן and ראש of that Beis Knesses who started the procedure of handing the Sefer Torah to the Kohen Gadol to read from on Yom Kippur).

Comment: Agav - there was a Beis haKise too! Tamid 26a (mishna): Rosh: ובית הכסא של כבוד. היה שם דתנן במסכת מקוואות בעל קרי שטבל ולא הטיל מים לכשיטול מים טמא ולכך עשו שם בית כסא להטיל מים קודם טבילה